# jquery getting all the values of the nearest element

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
<ul><li class="rjust">
    <a href="#" class="edit-video-lightbox" id="4f80a4b5">Edit</a>
    <input type="hidden" class="video_title" value="test123">
    <input type="hidden" class="video_description" value="Sample Description">
    <input type="hidden" class="video_tags" value="Adjust">
    <input type="hidden" class="video_tags" value="TXV">
</li>

<li class="rjust">
        <a href="#" class="edit-video-lightbox" id="235235">Edit</a>
        <input type="hidden" class="video_title" value="another_test">
        <input type="hidden" class="video_description" value="descriptme agian">
        <input type="hidden" class="video_tags" value="tag1">
        <input type="hidden" class="video_tags" value="tag2">
</li></ul>
```

When I click on the "Edit" a href, I want to get all the values of the class "video_tags" nearest to it. 
Example when the 1st "Edit" is being click (id="4f80a4b5"), I want to get all the value of the "video_tags" which is "Adjust", "TXV". 
On the other hand, when I click on the other "Edit" (id="235235"), all the value of "video_tags" that I should get is "tag1","tag2" since it obviously it is near to it.

Take note that the class "video_tags" is flexible, it could have many classes, my example has just only 2 video_tags per li.

Kindly please help me with this matter.
 Any help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
var tags;
$(".edit-video-lightbox").click(function() {
    tags = [];
    $(this).siblings('.video_tags').each(function() {
          tags.push($(this).val());
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a .siblings() method for this in jQuery:

```
$('.edit-video-lightbox').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('input.video_tags').each(function() {
    //this keyword refers to sibling element
    //user this.value to retrieve element's value
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I know, three answers already. But just wanted to highlight both [the new `on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) introduced in jQuery 1.7, as well as [the nifty `map` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) from jQuery 1.0:

```
function getVal(elem) {
    return elem.value;
}

function getVals(e) {
    var tags = $(e.target).siblings('.video_tags'),
        values = $.map(tags, getVal);
    e.preventDefault();
    // do whatever you want with `values` here
}

$('ul').on('click', '.edit-video-lightbox', getVals);
```